# What's wrong with this MySQL query and PHP foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me learn what is wrong with this PHP / MySQL query.

This is my channels table:

```
name    url              id      key
BBC2    http://url.com/2 BBC2   2
BBC1    http://url.com/1 BBC1   1
```

This works:

```PHP
$getchans = "SELECT * FROM channels";  
$channels = mysqli_query($db,$getchans);    
foreach ($channels as $channel)
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

This does not work:

```
$getchans = "SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY key ASC";  
$channels = mysqli_query($db,$getchans);    
foreach ($channels as $channel)
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

and gives error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Can anyone please tell me why it doesn't work when MySQL query/result  is ordered?

Thank you.

Comment: change your table name key to idchannnel and try again

Answer (score 2):

esacepe Key Keyword, [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

```
$getchans="SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY `key` ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

key is a keyword in mysql so you need to use `` quotes in your query.

$getchans="SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY `key` ASC";

Answer (score 0):

Your query failed because `key` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Try to change the name of the column `key` to something else. There is also a very usefull list with all the reseverd keywords.

If you don't prefer an other name for this column, you can try to escape it by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM channels ORDER BY `key` ASC
```

List with reserved keywords can be found on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately now it is not ordering correctly but I found a fix, adding +0 to the query field. 
 SELECT * FROM channels1 ORDER BY 'keyid+0' ASC;